# Second derivation of $\sin^2(xy) $

Tags: derivatives

I have this equation $\sin^2(xy)=0$ and I should count it's first and second derivation on in point x0

Note: $[x_0,y_0] = [1, π]$

I have done it with the first derivation like this:

$y'=-\frac{Fx}{Fy}=-\frac{y\sin(2xy)}{x\sin(2xy)}=-\frac{\pi\sin(2\pi)}{1\sin(2\pi)}=0$

**But** fraction bottom value can not be equal zero:

$1\sin(2\pi)=0$! is equal zero.

Does it mean that the first derivation does not have value?

**Now** the second derivation:

$y''=-\frac{(y'\sin(2xy)+y\cos(2xy)2y)-(\sin(2xy)+xcos(2xy)2y)}{(x\sin(2xy))^2}=?$

**This is what I have but I do not know if it is correct and if I can event find the second derivation value if the first one does not exist.**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with implicit differentiation of the function $f(x,y)$

$${\rm d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} {\rm d} x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} {\rm d} y = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + y' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) {\rm d}x $$

So your first derivative becomes

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \sin^2(xy) + y' \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial y} \sin^2(xy) \right) =0 $$

$$ 2 y \sin(x y) \cos(x y) + y' \left( 2 x \sin(x y) \cos(x y) \right) = 0 $$
$$ y' =-\frac{y}{x} $$

The second derivative now becomes much simpler

$$ y'' = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(-\frac{y}{x}\right) + y' \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left(-\frac{y}{x}\right) = \frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{y'}{x}$$

Hence $$y'' = \frac{2 y}{x^2} $$

Comment: So y'=-pi and y''= 2pi, right? :)

Comment: Yes $y'=-\pi$ and $y''=2\pi$